# What does this に力を入れていますmean? In what context do you use this?

Tags: meaning

My Japanese friend online said it means important and in some translating sites, I found it means focusing or put emphasis in. They're all similar but what does に力を入 actually stand for, specifically? Because I can't find any translation for it. It's not actually a word, is it?

Comment: Mm, how much Japanese grammar do you understand? This is not a single word, but a weird lopped off part of a sentence. The noun before に is quite important.

Comment: https://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E5%8A%9B%E3%82%92%E5%85%A5%E3%82%8C%E3%82%8B

Answer (score 3):

- ～に: "in/into ～"
- 力【ちから】: "power", "energy", "effort"
- を: direct object marker
- 入れて: te-form of 入れる ("put in")
- います: progressive marker

So ～に力を入れています means "[I am / We are] putting energy/effort in ～". Depending on the context, it can mean "[I/We] consider ～ important", but it's not a literal translation.